# Like button doesn't work with any Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page

Apparently, something happened with facebook that i cannot like any Facebook page (in ex. http://www.facebook.com/TheSimpsons).
You can like such page on a page itself but not via Like button on your website.
Even on facebook documentation page (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) if you put this url and try to click generated button, it will like and immediately unlike it.

Are there any known reason for such behavior or workaround?

Comment: Looks like this bug is already registered in FB bugtracker: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/431116883591090?browse=search_505c401a1bcb78c13888236

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was Facebook bug which is closed now